# Failed cast: IList<T> to Custom Class implementing ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, exception, collections, casting

This is my custom collection declaration.

```
public interface IMenuCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
public class HTMLMenuCollection: IMenuCollection<HTMLMenu>
```

I am trying to cast to it from another collection `IList<T>`.

```
IList<HTMLMenu> htmlMenuList = new List<HTMLMenu>();
...
HTMLMenuCollection tempColl = (HTMLMenuCollection)htmlMenuList;
```

I have no idea why this won't work.  If I cast `IList<T>` to `ICollection<T>` it works just fine, but with this I get an invalid cast exception. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of inheritance as a 'is a' relationship.

Then you can think of it as being because `HTMLMenuCollection` is a `List<HTMLMenu>` but not every `List<HTMLMenu>` is a `HTMLMenuCollection` (since `List<HTMLMenu>` doesn't inherit from `HTMLMenuCollection`).

The reason that you can cast from a List to IList to ICollection is the following:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T> // and more
```

and

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T> // and more
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't cast because `List<HTMLMenu>` simply does not implement `HTMLMenuCollection`, even if it has the same set of members.

Comment: Ok, I am being dense I guess.  IList<T> implements ICollection<T> shouldn't it use that common reference to make the cast?

Comment: @joshlrogers - Having a common reference isn't enough. They are implemented differently. IList could implement several features that HTMLMenuCollection does not implement (thus making them incompatible).

Answer (score 0):

`HTMLMenuCollection` does not implement `IList`. The `ICollection` cast works because they both inherit from `ICollection`.

Also, you're upcasting from a `List` to an `HTMLMenuCollection`, which won't work because `HTMLMenuCollection` is not inheriting from `List`, and regardless the upconvert can't work since the compiler will consider `HTMLMenuCollection` to have more data (even if it doesn't) than a `List`.

It might be more useful to pass the list into a constructor, and have the internal implementations of the `ICollection` methods just pass to whatever container field you're storing it in internally.

Answer (score 0):

Casting in .net is done at run-time, so you must look at the type of the instance instead of the declared type of the variable. The type of `htmlMenuList` instance is `List<HTMLMenu>`, which cannot be casted to `HTMLMenuCollection` because `List<HtmlMenu>` is not, and does not inherited from `HtmlMenuCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around could be to use the `AddRange(IEnumerable<HtmlMenu>)` method that is provided to `HtmlMenuCollection` through the implementation of `ICollection<HtmlMenu>`.